# Magic Zoom Plus breaks scroll on touch and mobile devices

Tags: mobile, scroll, touch, drag, magiczoomplus

I've just added Magic Zoom Plus to a page and it's working as expected on desktop.

However, when viewing on a mobile or touch screen device, you can't scroll/drag past the image, so if your image takes up most of the screen, it makes it very difficult to scroll past it.

I've checked their [integration docs](https://www.magictoolbox.com/magiczoomplus/integration/) but can't find anything which talks about allowing dragging/scrolling on touch/mobile devices.

Does anyone know of a way to fix this or a way around it?

---

**UPDATE - 26/08/2015**

I realised the version I was supplied with was an older version and updating to a newer version (v4.5.41) fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Either enable the click-to-activate setting:

https://www.magictoolbox.com/magiczoomplus/integration/#activate

Or better, wait 2 weeks until 8 September 2015 when Magic Zoom Plus v5.0 will be released. One of the improvements in version 5.0 is native support for dragging the page through the image.

Comment: I realised the version I was supplied with was an older version and updating to a newer version (v4.5.41) fixed my issue. I've updated original question with this detail.

Thanks for the heads up re: v5.0.